# Google Analytics Interface - Adding onLoad Event to Goals

Tags: google-analytics, onload-event

Hey I'm having some trouble using the Google Analytics interface and wondering if anyone has ever experienced this.

I recently added an onLoad event to track certain pages of a site but I can't seem to understand how to add the Goals to my Analytics account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this information from here and put it into "Goal Type:Event" Section 1

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', `'category', 'action', 'opt_label', opt_value`]);

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with terminology here since "event" is ambigous - did you add a Javascript onload event handler to your page (which wouldn't be necessary for GA tracking) or do you want to use Google Analytics event tracking (which is was Silas assumed) ?

In any case, Analytics Goal are created in the admin section in your account, under profile settings->goals. There you have to enter a unique name and a type.

Type "Url destination" mean your visitors have reached a particular page (goal url) in your website (either the precise url (match type "exact"), a url that starts with your goal url (head match) or a url that matches a given pattern (regular expression).

If people are supposed to follow a given path before they visit the goal url you can create a funnel by checking the "Use funnel" checkbox and enter the individual urls they have to visit before getting to the goal url. That's useful especially if you have some sort of checkout process - the funnel visualization report will show you how many people exited the process before they reached your goal url and at which url (high exit rate at a given steps means there is a problem and you should optimize this particular page).

In the same way you can create a goal for a google analytics event, only those do not have funnels (an event has more or less by definition only one step).

Comment: they added a choice to their options now that is "Event" to be used to track like "Thank You Pages, and such